# jQuery event handler among other handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-events

I'm writing a jQuery plugin for tracking events on a page with Google Analytics. I have a simple loop for elements which attaches an event handler to each one. It works great for tracking clicks on `div` and such.

```
$('a.tracked').tracking();

(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.tracking = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', 'value');
            });
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Tracking didn't work on links though, so I added a test which delays the default behaviour until the tracking callback happens:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.tracking = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function(event){
                if ($(this).prop('tagName')=='A'){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', 'value', {'hitCallback':function(){
                        document.location = url;
                    }});
                }else{
                    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', 'value');
                }
            });
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Works great too! However, *I want to track "cleverer" links which already have event handlers, such as lightbox or web app links*.

1. Is there a way to force my event handler to be called *before* other event handlers?
2. Can I "pause" other handlers before tracking, and "resume" them in the callback?
3. Is this approach as flexible/useful as I hope it will be?

Comment: `this.each(function() {` is redundant in your code, fyi. `this.on(...` would do the same recursion.

Comment: 1: no. 2: depends on when they're bound. You could use a jquery plugin called "holdReady" if they're all done in document ready, otherwise you'll have to handle it on a case-by-case basis. 3: dunno.